# Can we set remote_tmp value in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to set different value of remote_tmp variable in ansible for each playbook. Is it possible to define this variable value in playbook?

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"Can we set remote_tmp value **in ansible playbook**?"*

A: Yes. You can set [ansible_remote_tmp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html#parameter-remote_tmp). For example, the playbook below uses the default value `~/.ansible/tmp`

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_remote_tmp
    - shell: uname -a

shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -vvv

TASK [debug] ****
task path: /export/scratch/tmp/playbook.yml:3
ok: [test_01] => 
  ansible_remote_tmp: 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!:
                      ''ansible_remote_tmp'' is undefined'

TASK [shell] ****
task path: /export/scratch/tmp/playbook.yml:5
<test_01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
... echo /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1599833593. ...
```

In the playbook below the remote tmp is set to `/tmp`

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01
  vars:
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_remote_tmp
    - shell: uname -a

shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -vvv

TASK [debug] ****
task path: /export/scratch/tmp/playbook.yml:11
ok: [test_01] => 
  ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp

TASK [shell] ****
task path: /export/scratch/tmp/playbook.yml:13
<test_01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
... echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1599833597. ...
```

Comment: Then how can we set up the ansible so that it can work for both linux and windows? What value of remote_tmp can be set?

Comment: See [Operating System Dependent Tasks](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/os-dependent-tasks/variables/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. As a variable the parameter is called `ansible_remote_tmp`.

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/sh.html#parameter-remote_tmp